# SF short story about treatment of mentally ill man with sound of electricity

Tags: story-identification

Published likely before 1985, maybe in an SF anthology.

Doctor is asked by man's girlfriend or wife to help him. The patient oscillates between charming attractive persona and violent abusive persona. Various treatments are tried. Eventually the doctor finds a way to trigger or power the treatment from the ambient background sound of AC electricity (50 or 60 hz). The treatment is a success but the wife or girlfriend is sad, since the "normalized" persona of the man can never provide the joy she experienced when the "angelic" persona was uppermost.

Answer (score 3):

This is the 1956 story "[The Other Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45921)" by Theodore Sturgeon.  Here's the end of the note that the subject's significant other leaves the doctor:

> But Fred- this is hateful of me, I know - the thing I told you about,
> the thing I used to wish for and live to remember, no matter
> what...it's gone.  That's probably good, because of what happened
> between times.
>
> But sometimes I'd trade my perfect husband for that
> louse and a wet handkerchief, if I could have the other thing along
> with it somehow.
>
> There, I've said it.